# document.getElementById("id").innerHTML doesn't work but console.log does. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I designed a piece of code where a function is used to make the input to uppercase. When I have the result I output it through `console.log` where it works perfectly but when I tried to use `document.getElementById("SomeId").innerHTML = output;` it doesn't work.

I am running Deepin Linux (based on Debian) and am using Visual Studio Code with node.js and npm installed.

```js
function up(name) {

  this.name = name.toUpperCase();
};
var nm = prompt("Type in your name in a jumble of capital and lowercase letters!");
var out = new up(nm);
//this works
console.log(out.name);
//this doesn't
document.getElementById("uppercase");
```

```html
  <h1 id="upppercase">Hey</h1>
  <p id="smallcase"></p>
```

I would expect the same output as `console.log();`

Comment: `document.getElementById("uppercase")` returns an DOM element,but you do nothing with it. Try `document.getElementById("uppercase").innerHTML = out.name` to see the same output on the screen as was in the console.

Comment: I would advise reading some JS docs and re-evaluating why you think getting an element by id would print to console https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: What I don't understand is that in the OP's description they mention "`document.getElementById("SomeId").innerHTML = output;` it doesn't work", yet the code example doesn't reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit confused.

1) Your h1 accidentally has the id `upppercase` with 3 `p`s in it

2) Your `up()` function assigns the variable to `this`, which doesn't make sense

3) You have to use `.textContent = ...` to put text into a DOM node

Try this:

```js
function up(name) {
    return name.toUpperCase();
};

var nm = prompt("Type in your name in a jumble of capital and lower case letters!");
var out = up(nm);
var h1 = document.querySelector("#uppercase");
h1.textContent = out;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prototype</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="uppercase">Hey</h1>
        <p id="smallcase"></p>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *You have to use .innerHTML = ... to put content into a DOM node* << No, you don't and you should only use `.innerHTML` when the string contains HTML, otherwise always use `.textContent`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus True! I usually append HTML, so it is a force of habit. Not much of a difference though, but I'll amend my post - thank you!

Comment: It's a huge difference. `innerHTML` has performance and security implications and if the element you are using it on has any child elements that had event handlers set up on them, all those handlers will be wiped out. It should be the very last choice when injecting content into the DOM.

Comment: @ScottMarcus As far as performance, in these small cases it is negligible. In terms of XSS, it is also negligible unless the code being appended is dynamic (from what I understand!)

Comment: The performance will depend on what the content being appended is. Since we can't know that when we provide answers here, it's not a good idea to show a technique that can lead to big problems. In this question, the text is static, but so many people advocate `.innerHTML` that newbies only learn that and wind up using it later when the text is dynamic. Also, there is still the event registration issue.

Comment: Really, the best thing is to just never use `.innerHTML` at all and simply use the DOM to create new elements when they are needed.

Comment: Fair enough - I am used to using `.text()` with jQuery, and didn't even realize there is a native implementation. I like your idea of staying on the safe side when giving advice to newbies though, since you are correct that they may stick to initial habits. Can you elaborate on "event registration issue" though? I am not familiar with that term.

Comment: If you have an element that has child elements and those children have event handlers set up on them (`click`. `change`, etc.), those elements will be wiped out and replaced with new ones (that don't have any events set up) if you do something like this: `element.innerHTML += someNewStuff`.

Comment: Very very interesting, I had never heard about that. Thank you for the information! I will be sure to implement it more carefully in the future.

Comment: @Hybrid sorry it was just my mistake in typing in the code correctly and also i didn't spell uppercase correctly in the html but i did spell it correctly in javascript. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your `h1` and an `id` of `upppercase` (3 p's) and your code tries to find `uppercase`.

Also, you don't need a constructor function with `new` and `this` here.

Lastly, you must set the content of the `h1` to be its old content plus a space and the new output. You were just getting a reference to the element, but not doing anything with that reference.

```js
function up(name) {
    return name.toUpperCase();
};
var nm = prompt("Type in your name in a jumble of capital and lower case letters!");

// Concatenate the name to the extisting text in the H1
document.getElementById("uppercase").textContent += " " + up(nm);
```

```html
<h1 id="uppercase">Hey</h1>
<p id="smallcase"></p>
```

If you really wanted to use a constructor function so that you could have an object with methods, this would be more appropriate:

```js
// Constructor functions are named using Pascal Case by convention
function Up(name) {
   // Create two methods for the object
   this.makeUpper = function() { return name.toUpperCase(); };
   this.makeLower = function() { return name.toLowerCase(); };   
};
var nm = prompt("Type in your name in a jumble of capital and lower case letters!");

// Make an instance:
let myCaseMaker = new Up(nm);

// Use the object and concatenate the name to the extisting text in the H1
document.getElementById("uppercase").textContent += " " + myCaseMaker.makeUpper();
document.getElementById("smallcase").textContent += " " + myCaseMaker.makeLower();
```

```html
<h1 id="uppercase">Hey</h1>
<p id="smallcase"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because in this line:

```
document.getElementById("uppercase");
```

You're not doing anything. You're not actually modifying the DOM. You ned to use `innerHTML`:

```js
function up(name) {
  this.name = name.toUpperCase();
};
var nm = prompt("Type in your name in a jumble of capital and lower case letters!");
var out = new up(nm);

console.log(out.name);
document.getElementById("upppercase").textContent = out.name;
```

```html
<h1 id="upppercase">Hey</h1>
<p id="smallcase"></p>
```

Comment: lol you coulve edited it to be grammatically correct ... but no you chose to use the version with 3ps :D